# SQL Sub Query returning no value, but junit test is still passing

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, junit, junit4

Below is a sub-query that I am trying to use in a junit test.

The below code is passing, when the test should be failing.

The value I am using ***(this.Id)*** does not exist in the tlink, so the sub-query should return no record. (I.e. no record exists in tlink for that extId)

But, the test is still passing.

```
try {
        dbAccessSetUp();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) as total FROM taddress WHERE address_id = (SELECT address_id FROM tlink WHERE ext_id =" + this.ID + ")");

        if(!rs.next()) {
            fail("Record does not exist in taddress");
        }
        int count = 0;
        while(rs.next()) {              
            count = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("number of count : " + count);
            assertTrue(0 < count);
        } 
        rs.close(); 
    } catch(SQLException se) { 
        se.printStackTrace(); 
        assertEquals(true, false);
    } catch(Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
        assertEquals(true, false);
    } finally { 
        try { 
            if(stmt!=null) stmt.close();  
        } catch(SQLException se2) {
            assertEquals(true, false);
        } 
        try { 
            if(conn!=null) conn.close(); 
        } catch(SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace(); 
            assertEquals(true, false);
        } 
    }
```

Does anyone know why this method isn't working?
Also, the System.out isn't being displayed, so it's not actually going into the while loop, but the test is still passing rather than failing.

Comment: `WHERE address_id = (SELECT address_id FROM...` That will throw an error if the subquery return more than one row

Comment: To add to the above comment, you should check to see if any exception is being thrown, which might also be resulting in a failure.  By the way, strictly speaking testing an actual database is not a unit test, it's an _integeration_ test.

Answer (score 1):

> The value I am using (this.Id) does not exist in the tlink, so the sub-query should return no record. (I.e. no record exists in tlink for that extId)

The query you are using is:

```
SELECT count(*) as total
FROM taddress
WHERE address_id = (SELECT address_id FROM tlink WHERE ext_id =" + this.ID + ")")
```

(Note:  parameters are highly recommended rather than munging a query string.)

This query is *always* going to return exactly one row (unless there is an error, which you should be checking for, particularly for an audit test).  If nothing matches the `where` clause, then `total` will be `0`.

That explains why `fail()` is not being called -- an contradicts your statement in the question.

Why doesn't the `assert()` fail?  Well, you already checked for the first record, so I think it is moving onto the second one.  Hence, the `while` loop is not being called.  You should just look up the single returned value once and check if it is 0.

Comment: Hi, thanks, this helps a lot. Could you provide a snippet that'll check that no record exists in taddress (in a more efficient way than what I'm doing at the moment)?

Comment: @user9847788 . . . New questions should be asked as *new* questions.  This question is about why your existing code is not working.  If you want a more efficient query, then ask a question that includes sample data and a clear explanation of what you want to check for.